# Clearing the Bonding(Pairing) Information through BLE in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have to remove the pairing(Bonding) information from the Device, but after executing that and go back to Bluetooth settings and check the paired devices it is still showing as paired. It is not clearing the information.
The address we provided is:`F8:F6:35:D6:35:64`

Thank's in advance for the solution.

Comment: Please post what code you tried to use in order to remove the bonding/pairing. The more code from the class you share, the faster and better we will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

This has to be handled in platform specific code.

On iOS it is not possible. Only manually "forgetting" in the settings. [See here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/135732#135732)

For the Android Part [see here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43645/unpair-bluetooth-programatically).

Answer (score 0):

For android,get the Bluetooth list paired by the phone in one way and then cancel the Bluetooth pairing through the reflection mechanism.

```
 BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    IEnumerable<BluetoothDevice> bondeddevices;


    private void  removepairdevice()
    {
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
         bondeddevices = bluetoothAdapter.BondedDevices;
        foreach(BluetoothDevice device in bondeddevices)
        {
            unpairdevice(device);
        }
    }
    private void unpairdevice(BluetoothDevice device)
    {
        try
        {
            Method m = device.Class.GetMethod("removeBond",null);
            m.Invoke(device,null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```